# How can I combine \b txt and and \# formatting in Word's mailmerge?

Tags: microsoft-word, mail-merge

I would like to both format a field and add text before it.

This works:

```
{MERGEFIELD m_002 \b "Dollars need for purchase:"}
```

Producing:

```
Dollars needed for purchase: 1250
```

But when I add a format picture it breaks.

```
{MERGEFIELD m_002 \# $,0.00 \b "Dollars need for purchase:"}
```

Producing:

```
$1,250.02
```

What I would like to see is:

```
Dollars needed for purchase: $1,250.00
```

Answer (score 0):

This produces the desired result if m_002 has a value or no result if m_002 is null or zero.

```
{MERGEFIELD m_002 \# "Dollars need for purchase:$,0.00;;"}
```